# Primary structures in $\mathbb Q$

Tags: nt.number-theory, ac.commutative-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras, prime-numbers

I'll formulate a topic restricted here to the positive rational
numbers $\ \mathbb Q_{_{>0}},\ $, then will pose a question (**Q2**) plus some related, to which I don't know the answers nor reference. The idea is to understand how general is the notion of the set of all prime numbers:
do we or don't we have other similar objects which I call primary structures.

> **STANDARD TERMINOLOGY**

$\mathbb N := \{1\ 2\ \ldots\}\ $ -- the set of natural numbers;
$\mathbb Z_+:=\mathbb N\cup\{0\}\ $ --  the set on nonnegative integers;
$\mathbb Z\ $ -- the ring of (rational) integers;
$\mathbb Q\ $ -- the field of rational numbers;
$\mathbb Q_{_{>0}} := \{x\in \mathbb Q : x > 0\}\ $ -- the set of positive rational numbers.
$\mathbb P:= (2\ 3\ 5\ 7\ 11\ \ldots)\ $ -- the **sequence** of all primes (i.e. $P_1:=2,\ $ and $\ P_5:= 11,\ $ etc.).

> **SPECIAL TERMINOLOGY**

$\Omega := \{f\in \mathbb Z^\mathbb N:\sum|f|<\infty\}\ $ -- integer sequences with finitely many non-zero values;
$\Lambda := \{f\in \mathbb Z_+^\mathbb N:\sum f<\infty\} = \mathbb Z_+^\mathbb N\cap \Omega;$
$x^f := \prod_{n\in\mathbb N} x_n^{f(n)}\ $ for every sequence $x:=(x_1\ x_2\ \ldots)\ $ of positive rationals, and for $\ f\in \Omega$;
$x^* := \{x^f:f\in\Lambda\}\ $ -- the multiplicative monoid
generated by terms of sequence $x$.
$\mathbb Q(x) := \{x^f:f\in\Omega\}\ $

> **DEFINITIONS**

Let $\ S:=(S_1\ S_2\ \ldots)\in \mathbb Q_{_{>0}}\!^\mathbb N$.

**D1.** $\ $ Sequence $S\ $ has the *unique decomposition property* (*u.d.p.* for short)
$\Leftarrow:\Rightarrow$

$$ \forall_{f\ g\in\Omega}\ \left(S^f = S^g\,\ \Rightarrow\,\ f=g\right) $$

**Note 1.** $\ $ Replacing $\ \Omega\ $ by $\ \Lambda\ $ would not affect the above definition.
**Note 2.** $\ \forall_{x\ y\in S^*}\ \left(x\cdot y=1\,\ \Rightarrow\,\ x=y=1\right)$

There are plenty of sequences with the u.d.p. However one extra condition will narrow the choice drastically:

**D2.** $\ $ A u.d.p. sequence $\ S\ $ is called a *primary structure* $\ \Leftarrow:\Rightarrow\ S^*\ $ is an additive semigroup in $\ Q_{_{>0}}$.

> **QUESTIONS**

Let $\ S\ $ be an arbitrary primary structure. Is it true that:

**Q1:** $\ \forall_{n\in\mathbb N}\ S_n > 1\ ?$

**Q2:** Is $\ S\ $ a permutation of $\ \mathbb P$?

If *NO* to Q2 (just in case :-), we may still wonder about:

**Q3:** If every prime appears in $\ S\ $ is it true that only
primes appear in $\ S\ $ (i.e. that $\ S\ $ is a permutation
of $\ \mathbb P$)?

**Q4.** $\ \mathbb Q(S) = \mathbb Q\ $?

Comment: I could add examples of u.d.p. sequences for which it is not obvious that they are not additive monoids (i.e. that they are not primary structures). The QUESTION is already a bit long but I could do it.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek, thank you for pointing to my typos. I've fixed them by now. It was not just $\ S\ $ but the induced multiplicative monoid $\ S^*;\ $ and it was also supposed to be an additive **semigroup** -- not an additive monoid. Sorry for the typos.

Comment: OK, now it makes sense.

Comment: Q3 and Q4 are easy: Q3 follows from the fact that every positive rational is a ratio of products of primes, and Q4 from the fact that by D2, $S^*$ includes $\mathbb N$. Which actually implies a generalization of Q3: any primary structure is maximal (it is not properly included in another udp).

Comment: @EmilJeřábek, thank you for answering my *just in case* questions. For the sake of the completeness of the thread you may still enter your text as an ***Answer***, including your observation about the maximality of the primary structures. Question **Q2** is still the key.

Comment: OK. I was hoping for someone (possibly me) to throw some light on the real question, but as this didn't happen, I've expanded the comment to an answer.

Answer (score 3):

Since there were so far no takers for the main question, let me state for the record that Q3 and Q4 are true, as already mentioned in the comments.

If $S$ is a primary structure, then $S^*$ is an additive semigroup containing $1$, whence $\mathbb N\subseteq S^*$, and a fortiori $\mathbb Q(S)=\mathbb Q$. Thus Q4 is true.

Notice that the properties of being a u.d.p. and being a primary structure are invariant under permutations, and any u.d.p. is an injective sequence. Thus, there is no loss in treating u.d.p.s and primary structures as *sets* rather that sequences (where a set of rationals is defined to be a u.d.p. if some/every its injective enumeration is a u.d.p., and likewise for p.s.).

With this in mind, every p.s. is a maximal u.d.p.: that is, there are no p.s. $S$ and u.d.p. $S'$ such that $S\subsetneq S'$. Indeed, any $a\in S'\smallsetminus S$ is also in $\mathbb Q(S)$ by the argument above, which gives a nontrivial multiplicative relation among elements of $S'$.

In particular, this implies a positive answer to Q3, as the set of primes is itself a p.s.

Comment: Emil,  thank you for your answer. And let's still hope for more.

Answer (score 0):

The example below illustrates the questions without solving any of them.

**EXAMPLE** $\ $ Let $\ \mathbb P=(P_1\ P_2\ \ldots)\ $ be the increasing sequence of all primes. Let

(i) $\ S_1 := 2$;
(ii) $\ \forall_{n>1}\ S_n := \frac{P_n}{P_{n-1}}$.

Then sequence $\ S:=(S_1\ S_2\ \ldots)\ $ has the following properties:

(1) $\ S\ $ has the u.d.p.;
(2) $\ \mathbb Q(S) = \mathbb Q$;
(3) $\ S^* \supseteq\mathbb N$;
(4) $\ S\ $ is not a primary structure (i.e. $\ S^*\ $ is
    not closed under addition).

**PROOF**

**(1)** Let's apply the $\ \Lambda\ $ version of the definition
of *u.d.p.* Let $\ f\ g\in\Lambda\ $ be such that $\ S^f=S^g.\ $
If $\ f\ $ is the zero sequence then $\ S^f=1,\ $ and it's clear
that also $\ g\ $ is a zero sequence. Otherwise $\ f\ $ is a
nonzero sequence. Then there exists a unique largest
prime $\ P_n\ $ which appears in the standard prime decomposition
of the rational number $\ S^f\ $ (the same primes in the similar
way appears in $\ S^g\, $ since $\ S^f=S^g).\ $ Then $\ f(n)>0\ $
and $\ g(n)>0,\ $ hence

$$S^f=S_n\cdot S^{f'}\qquad and \qquad S^g=S_n\cdot S^{g'}$$

where $\ f'(k)=f(k)\ $ and $\ g'(k)=g(k)\ $ for every $\ k\ne n,\ $
and $\ f(n)-f'(n) = g(n)-g'(n) = 1.\ $ Thus $\ S^{f'} = S^{g'}\ $ which by induction on $\ \sum f\ $ implies that $\ f'=g'.\ $ This induction proves that the *u.d.p.* holds for $\ S$.

**(2&3)**

$$ \forall_{n\in\mathbb N}\ P_n = \prod_{k=1}^n\,S_k $$

Thus $\ \mathbb P\subseteq S^*.\ $ It follows that
$\ \mathbb N\subseteq S^*,\ $ and $\ \mathbb Q\subseteq \mathbb Q(S)$.

**(4)** Note that $\ P(3)=5\ $ and $\ P_8=19.\ $ Thus
$$ S_2 + S_3\ = \frac{19}{2\cdot 3}\ =
  \ S_1^{-1}\cdot \prod_{k=3}^8 S_k\ \notin\ S^* $$

because $\ S_2+S_3\ = S^f\ $ where $\ f(1) = -1,\ $
hence $\ f\notin \Lambda,\ $ (apply the $\Omega$ version of the definition
of the *u.d.p.*). But, of course, $\ S_2\ S_3\in S^*.\ $ Thus $\ S^*\ $
is not closed under addition.

**END of proof**

> *Well, just a measly example.*